# DateTime object is getting changed when a different variable is being assigned

Tags: php, object

In order to get the current [datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and the [datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) of 2 days ago I wrote the following code;

```
$now        = new \DateTime();
$twoDaysAgo = $now->sub(new \DateInterval('P2D'));
```

When I run `var_dump($now, $twoDaysAgo);` The result is as follows.

```
// $now
object(DateTime)#496 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2014-08-04 16:31:08"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}

// $twoDaysAgo
object(DateTime)#496 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2014-08-04 16:31:08"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Both the variables have the same value of $twoDaysAgo. To get the desired values I did the following;

```
$now        = new \DateTime();
$twoDaysAgo = new \DateTime();
$twoDaysAgo = $twoDaysAgo->sub(new \DateInterval('P2D'));
```

My Question is, why were the values of $now and $twoDaysAgo the same after the assignment of $twoDaysAgo instead of $now being the current datetime value?

Comment: RTFM `Subtracts an amount of days, months, years, hours, minutes and seconds from a DateTime object`.... subtracts it from the DateTime object that you call it against; and then you're simpky assigning that modified datetime object to a new variable, effectively just a new reference to the same modified object.... your thinking is procedural, not OOP

Comment: @MarkBaker it looks like according to the manual, both methods modify the object - `Parameters -> object -> Procedural style only: A DateTime object returned by date_create(). The function modifies this object.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`::sub()` will change the object it is called on and then return itself.
The problem could be fixed by cloning `$now` before working with it, like so:

```
$now        = new \DateTime();
$twoDaysAgo = clone $now; // clone the current date object
$twoDaysAgo->sub(new \DateInterval('P2D')); // work with the clone
```